# Go Golang SMTP Script. Need to add BCC header

Tags: go, smtp

I am using this well known blank canvas for SMTP in Go.

I need to add in Bcc Blank Carbon Copy address to it but I have tried lots of things and nothing I am trying works which is strange...

I have tried adding in "headers["Bcc"] = "someemail@address.com" I am sure it is an easy modification.

Thanks in Advance..

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "net"
   "net/mail"
   "net/smtp"
   "crypto/tls"
)

func main() {

from := mail.Address{"", "username@example.tld"}
to   := mail.Address{"", "username@anotherexample.tld"}
subj := "This is the email subject"
body := "This is an example body.\n With two lines."

headers := make(map[string]string)
headers["From"] = from.String()
headers["To"] = to.String()
headers["Subject"] = subj

message := ""
for k,v := range headers {
    message += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
}
message += "\r\n" + body

servername := "smtp.example.tld:465"

host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(servername)

auth := smtp.PlainAuth("","username@example.tld", "password", host)

tlsconfig := &tls.Config {
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    ServerName: host,
}

conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", servername, tlsconfig)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
c, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
if err = c.Auth(auth); err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
if err = c.Mail(from.Address); err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
if err = c.Rcpt(to.Address); err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
w, err := c.Data()
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
_, err = w.Write([]byte(message))
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
err = w.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
c.Quit()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See the following segment from the [smtp#SendMail package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail)

> The msg parameter should be an RFC 822-style email with headers first, a blank line, and then the message body. The lines of msg should be CRLF terminated. The msg headers should usually include fields such as "From", "To", "Subject", and "Cc". **Sending "Bcc" messages is accomplished by including an email address in the to parameter but not including it in the msg headers.**

In other words, don't add them in the headers, just to the recepient list.

In your example boilerplate code, you would add a call to `c.Rcpt(...)` for each email in the bcc list, and that's it. Nothing to add to headers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `RCPT` line for the Bcc address too, for example:

```
if err = c.Rcpt("someemail@address.com"); err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
```

Comment: BCC is not a header, it's simply another recipient you deliver to by connecting to its mail server and delivering it as above.

Answer (score 0):

as user10753492 pointed out, the standard doesn't include the concepts of carbon copies. You'd need to add one RCPT TO for each recipient and then add bcc: sample@email.com to the body. The client will take care of the rest.